# Get-Win-Event How to filter specific event by RecordId with powershell?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I know my log file and EventID so I can filter all records for this event id like this:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName=$_.Logfile; ID=$_.EventIdentifier }
```

This returns all records for EventID without record number so I'm feeding the result into :

```
 | Format-Table -Property RecordId,LevelDisplayName
```

And I'm getting the  following result :

```
4461 Information     
4280 Error     
3833 Information     
3761 Information
```

Now I Should filter out by recordId record 4280 tried to use

```
| where {($_.RecordId -eq '4280' )
```

bu this returns nothing. My expected result should be

4280 Error

Comment: Not able to reproduce, works fine with both `Where RecordId -eq 4280l` and `Where {$_.RecordId -eq '4280'}`. Why do you want to filter on `RecordId` though?

Comment: Try - `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName=$_.Logfile; ID=$_.EventIdentifier } | where {$_.RecordId -eq '4280'} |  Select RecordId,LevelDisplayName`, I think the issue is that you are trying to filter (Where) after Formatting (Format-Table).

Answer (score 0):

```
get-eventlog -LogName <YourLogName> -Index <RecordofInterst>  | Format-List
```

For a hint, try this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 10
```

Note the field Index - open the record in Event Viewer - that field is the `EventRecordID`

How to get a record by EventRecordID/Index

```
get-eventlog -LogName System -Index 35811 | Format-List
```

PowerShell returns this as `Index`